# Looping all files in directory sorted by newest

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing application in node.js, and one of functions requires to loop all files sorted by newest (filenames are 1.ext, 2.ext, 3.ext). How I can do it?

Already tried this:

```
fs.readdir('./files', (err, files) => {
  var count = files.length
  for (let i of count) {
    var contents = fs.readFileSync(i+'.ext')
    var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents)
    console.log('Value:', jsonContent.value)
  }
```

I expect the output of "value" variable to be 2, but when I execute it, output is error "count is not iterable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use for loop as shown below.

```
fs.readdir('./files', (err, files) => {
  var count = files.length
  for (let i = 0;i<count;i++) {
    var contents = fs.readFileSync(i+'.ext')
    var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents)
    console.log('Value:', jsonContent.value)
  }
});
```